# Split string and keep demiliter with following text

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, split

I have a long string of text that I want to split into an array by the strings "#", "##" and "###".

I can do this with:

```
const text = "### foo ## foo # foo ### foo ## foo ### foo ### foo ### foo"

text.split(/#{1,3}/g)
```

Output:

```
 [ '',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo ',
          ' foo' ]
```

However this removes the hashtags, which I still need. I can also keep the hashtags, but they are just added as elements to the array, which is not desirable either.

```
text.split(/(#{1,3})/g)
```

Output:

```
[ '',   '###',   ' foo ',   '##',   ' foo ',   '#',   ' foo ', '###',   ' foo ',   '##',   ' foo ',   '###',   ' foo ',   '###',   ' foo ',   '###',   ' foo' ]
```

How can I split the text so that the text after the hashtags is included in the array element after the hashtag? So that the result would be like this.

Wanted result:

```
[ '### foo ',   '## foo ',   '# foo ',   '### foo ',   '## foo ',   '### foo ',   '### foo ',   '### foo' ]
```

Comment: Just do a match with `#{1,3}[^#]+`

Comment: Is it appropriate to call `#` a "hashtag" outside of twitter? The symbol is usually called a number, pound or hash sign.

Comment: @ctwheels shouldn't you answer the question?

Comment: I think this solve, too: #{1,3} \w+    consider taking or not a space after \w+, depending if you want it or not.

Comment: Here's a really convoluted version: `"### foo ## foo # foo ### foo ## foo ### foo ### foo ### foo".split(/(#+)/).filter(val => val.length).reduce((arr, val) => { if(val[0] == '#') arr.push(val); else arr[arr.length-1] += val; return arr }, [])`

Comment: @evolutionxbox There, I added an answer ;) also, `#` has way too many names, all of which I'd consider valid depending on its usage. [Number sign, comment sign, cross, hashtag, hex, octothorp, sharp, space, square, etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign)

Comment: Also, @Waltari, you could split on ` (?=#)` assuming there's always a space that precedes the `#` character, but I think my previous answer is more reliable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/RktOAh/2)

```
#{1,3}[^#]+
```

Use the above regex with the JavaScript `match()` function

```js
var str = "### foo ## foo # foo ### foo ## foo ### foo ### foo ### foo";
var matches = str.match(/#{1,3}[^#]+/g);
console.log(matches)
```

---

### Explanation

- `#{1,3}` Match between 1 and 3 of the number sign (or whatever you want to call the symbol) `#` character literally
- `[^#]+` Match 1 or more of any character not present in the set `#`

Comment: _forever number sign_ ;-P